# How do I enforce bool types checks on json with jmsserialize

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

How do I enforce boolean type checks while deserializing json using jmsserializerbunlde? i.e. how can I disallow an input like:

{"boolField": "false"}

from being deserialized and type cast to boolean true?

I am using jmsserializerbundle and the symfony2 validation library.

My model field annotations:

```
/**
 * @var bool
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Type(type="bool")
 * @Type(name="boolean")
 * @SerializedName("boolField")
 */
private $boolField;
```

I'm deserializing then running validation.

```
 $str = '{"boolField": "false"}';
 $object = $serializer->deserialize($str, TestModel::class, 'json');
 $validator->validate($object);
 print_r($object)


 TestModel Object 
 (
     [boolField:TestModel:private] => 1
 )
```

This returns no errors but has the side-effect of my model having the $boolField set to true.

If I remove the annotation @Type it will not deserialize.

I could change the jmserialize type to string then have a @PostDeserialize method to convert these strings into booleans but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
$str = '{"boolField": "false"}';
```

'boolField' is a string, not a boolean.

Maybe

```
$str = '{"boolField": false}';
```

will perform better.

(Untested)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the system generating the json so I am unable to make the change. I ended up using a PostDeserialize method to fix boolean string values.